# CF ContextMenu - (onOpen event???)

Tags: compact-framework

I have a CF application.
In some view i have a ContextMenu that shows OK.
Is there a way to catch an event as the menu is drawn/opened?

I need to do some things just as the menu is drawn, because doing it later (on menuitem click) is already too late.

regards

Comment: nevermind, i found popup event.

Comment: Answer your question yourself and then mark it as the accepted answer. You might even get some votes for it.

Comment: i have additional question:
whenever onPopup is fired the other event (mouseDown) is not fired. In this event i have some code, that tracks position where the user has tapped on screen. mouseDown has MouseEventArgs that keep position, while onPopup event has EventArgs that dont keep this information. How can i access location in onPopup event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update ... I used popup event.